# Android 4.1 and hidden "multiple users". Need user switcher on lock screen

Tags: java, android

I have activity with swither, but how to put it in (or replace) Lock Screen?

I'm geting java.lang.RuntimeException when I try start my switcher activity from BroadcastReceiver.

```
} else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
    Log.d(Tag, "unLock Screen");
    Intent lsIntent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(lsIntent);
}
```